# Trying to get average spend in a certain store in a certain town

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of transactions:

```
   customer_id         town  amount     category
0           n1     New York   12.50  Book Stores
1           n2     New York    4.49  Book Stores
2           n3     New York   11.70  Book Stores
3           n4     New York   15.00     Cable TV
4           n5     New York    7.00     Cable TV
5           n6     New York    6.00     Cable TV
6           n7     New York   15.00     Cable TV
7           n8     New York    7.00     Cable TV
8           n9     New York    7.00     Cable TV
9          la1  Los Angeles   15.00  Book Stores
10         la2  Los Angeles   15.99  Book Stores
11         la3  Los Angeles   15.00  Book Stores
12         la4  Los Angeles    7.00     Cable TV
13         la5  Los Angeles   15.99     Cable TV
14         la6  Los Angeles   15.00     Cable TV
15         la7  Los Angeles    7.00     Cable TV
```

**Two towns:** New York and Los Angeles.

**Two categories of spend:** Book Shops and Cable TV.

As you can see there are 9 people living in New York.

There are only three Book Shop transactions in New York so I would expect the average Book Shop spend to be: `($12.50 + $4.49 + $11.70) / 9 people = $3.18`

I am trying to convert this to a pandas function. I have tried many different `groupbys` and `pivots`, but it always treats the data as if there are only 3 people living in New York.

Here is some of what I have tried:

```
print('\nAttempt 1...\n')
print(new_df.groupby(['town','category'])['amount'].mean())
print('\nAttempt 2...\n')
print(new_df.groupby(['category','town'])['amount'].mean())
print('\nAttempt 2...\n')
print(pd.pivot_table(new_df,index=["category"],values=["amount"],columns=["town"],aggfunc=[np.mean],fill_value=0))


Attempt 1...

town         category   
Los Angeles  Book Stores   15.33
             Cable TV      11.25
New York     Book Stores    9.56
             Cable TV       9.50
Name: amount, dtype: float64

Attempt 2...

category     town       
Book Stores  Los Angeles   15.33
             New York       9.56
Cable TV     Los Angeles   11.25
             New York       9.50
Name: amount, dtype: float64

Attempt 2...

                   mean         
                 amount         
town        Los Angeles New York
category                        
Book Stores       15.33     9.56
Cable TV          11.25     9.50
```

I am getting $9.56 as an average each time for Book stores in New York.

How can I get the average using the whole population of New York, and not just the three people who bought Books?

If you want to use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()`:

```
{'customer_id': {0: 'n1',
  1: 'n2',
  2: 'n3',
  3: 'n4',
  4: 'n5',
  5: 'n6',
  6: 'n7',
  7: 'n8',
  8: 'n9',
  9: 'la1',
  10: 'la2',
  11: 'la3',
  12: 'la4',
  13: 'la5',
  14: 'la6',
  15: 'la7'},
 'town': {0: 'New York',
  1: 'New York',
  2: 'New York',
  3: 'New York',
  4: 'New York',
  5: 'New York',
  6: 'New York',
  7: 'New York',
  8: 'New York',
  9: 'Los Angeles',
  10: 'Los Angeles',
  11: 'Los Angeles',
  12: 'Los Angeles',
  13: 'Los Angeles',
  14: 'Los Angeles',
  15: 'Los Angeles'},
 'amount': {0: 12.5,
  1: 4.49,
  2: 11.7,
  3: 15.0,
  4: 7.0,
  5: 6.0,
  6: 15.0,
  7: 7.0,
  8: 7.0,
  9: 15.0,
  10: 15.99,
  11: 15.0,
  12: 7.0,
  13: 15.99,
  14: 15.0,
  15: 7.0},
 'category': {0: 'Book Stores',
  1: 'Book Stores',
  2: 'Book Stores',
  3: 'Cable TV',
  4: 'Cable TV',
  5: 'Cable TV',
  6: 'Cable TV',
  7: 'Cable TV',
  8: 'Cable TV',
  9: 'Book Stores',
  10: 'Book Stores',
  11: 'Book Stores',
  12: 'Cable TV',
  13: 'Cable TV',
  14: 'Cable TV',
  15: 'Cable TV'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

try calculating each aggregated value on its own: ie

```
amounts = df.groupby(['town', 'category']).amount.sum()
ncostumers = df.groupby(['town']).size()
o = amounts.unstack(level=0) / ncostumers
print(o)
```

```
town    Los Angeles New York
category        
Book Stores 6.570000    3.187778
Cable TV    6.427143    6.333333
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) using `aggfunc` as `sum` with [`pd.Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and divide them [`df.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html)

```
(df.pivot_table(index = 'category', columns='town', values='amount',aggfunc='sum').
    div(df['town'].value_counts())
)

             Los Angeles  New York
category
Book Stores     6.570000  3.187778
Cable TV        6.427143  6.333333
```

**EDIT:**

Changing `town` as index and `categories` as columns.

```
(df.pivot_table(index = 'town', columns='category', values='amount',aggfunc='sum').
    div(df['town'].value_counts(),axis=0)
)

category     Book Stores  Cable TV
Los Angeles     6.570000  6.427143
New York        3.187778  6.333333
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to set the index to be `town` instead of `category`, but I'm getting wrong values. Is that even possible? I know I can add `.T` to your code to put `town` in the index, but can it be done with `pivot_table` ?

Comment: @SCool Yes, you can change them but change `.div(df['town'].value_counts())` as `div` tries to divide values of matching columns default axis is `1`/`columns`, now axis would be `0`. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

First aggregate `sum`, get `MultiIndex`, first level is `Town`, which is divided by counts by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and last reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['town', 'category'])['amount'].sum()
         .div(df['town'].value_counts(), level=0)
         .unstack(level=0))
print (df1)
town         Los Angeles  New York
category                          
Book Stores     6.570000  3.187778
Cable TV        6.427143  6.333333
```

Similar solution, only changed order of column in first `groupby`, then is change level for division and in `unstack` is used second level, so no parameter `level`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['category', 'town'])['amount'].sum()
         .div(df['town'].value_counts(), level=1)
         .unstack())
print (df1)
town         Los Angeles  New York
category                          
Book Stores     6.570000  3.187778
Cable TV        6.427143  6.333333
```